# Markdown in cucumber/gherkin descriptions and html formatter

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, cucumberjs

I am trying to use Markdown in Gherkin/Cucumber feature's descriptions. What I learned from https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/

> Descriptions can be in the form of Markdown - formatters including the official HTML formatter support this.

Unfortunately, for a feature like:

```
Feature: Feature name

    Are you sure that _Markdown_ works for Feature **Descriptions**?

    Scenario: Scenario name
```

I got an HTML report which does not take Markdown formatting into account.
[image: cucumber HTML report]
Is this a bug, or does it require some additional configuration?

Best,
Tomasz

Comment: You may want to create a bug report at https://github.com/cucumber/html-formatter

Comment: Thank you, already created a bug report https://github.com/cucumber/html-formatter/issues/294

Comment: Cheers. Can't promise any one will look soon, but this does help get things fixed eventually.